# Azure SQL Server admin password policy

Tags: sql-server, azure, passwords, admin

We have an SQL server hosted on Azure with multiple databases on it. It has a Server Admin set up (not using AD) with a password.

After X months (I'm guessing every 3rd?) that password gets locked(?) and our application gets an error that the Login Failed for that Server Admin. We are guessing there is some default password policy set on the SQL server since we can simply do a password reset via overview page and it works again.

Now the questions are, is there a password policy set by default? Can we disable/change this policy? And if yes, how do we do it?

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-create-manage-server-portal

Thank you.

Comment: That link is for MySQL documentation, but you've tagged SQL Server here.

Comment: Yes, but I can't seem to find any documentation for SQL server admin in Azure DB. There it only seems to be for AD users:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-guest-users

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by default password expiration policy is enabled.

Use ALTER LOGIN to configure the password policy for the SQL Server login.

```
-- Syntax for SQL Server

ALTER LOGIN login_name
    {
    <status_option>
    | WITH <set_option> [ ,... ]
    | <cryptographic_credential_option>
    }
[;]

<status_option> ::=
        ENABLE | DISABLE

<set_option> ::=
    PASSWORD = 'password' | hashed_password HASHED
    [
      OLD_PASSWORD = 'oldpassword'
      | <password_option> [<password_option> ]
    ]
    | DEFAULT_DATABASE = database
    | DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = language
    | NAME = login_name
    | CHECK_POLICY = { ON | OFF }
    | CHECK_EXPIRATION = { ON | OFF }
    | CREDENTIAL = credential_name
    | NO CREDENTIAL

<password_option> ::=
    MUST_CHANGE | UNLOCK

<cryptographic_credentials_option> ::=
    ADD CREDENTIAL credential_name
  | DROP CREDENTIAL credential_name
```

**You need to set CHECK_POLICY to OFF.** When CHECK_POLICY is changed to OFF, the following behavior occurs:

- CHECK_EXPIRATION is also set to OFF.
- The password history is cleared.
- The value of lockout_time is reset.

For more details: [SQL Server Login Password Expiration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/policy-based-management/sql-server-login-password-expiration?view=sql-server-ver15), [ALTER LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

You can change the password expiration policy by using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

Connect to the Azure SQL Server using login credentials in SSMS.

[image]

1. In the object browser, navigate to the Security > Logins folder.
2. Find the login you are interested in reviewing.
3. Right click on the login and select 'Properties' option.
4. On the General tab, review the 'Enforce password policy' and the 'Enforce password expiration' configurations. Untick the "Enforce password expiration".

[image]

Comment: Alright, that confirms my suspicions. However, how do I access this on Azure? Is there an console on the Azure portal that you can write querys on?

Comment: You can do it on SSMS. Updating my answer with the details.

Comment: I've already tried this. There is no option 'Properties' when connecting to SQL server on Azure with SSMS.

Comment: ok. please try to execute it on SQL database query editor on azure portal. Eg: ALTER LOGIN <login_name>
WITH PASSWORD = '<password>', 
CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
refer: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/users/alter_login.php

Comment: Ah! That site is great! I used query:
SELECT * FROM master.sys.sql_logins;
I can see that the policy is already off... expire as well.

Comment: Ohh, yeah I tried the same and found that Azure SQL server doesn't support this statement and option. Since, Azure SQL server is a PaaS service, it doesn't allow to modify the default settings. I recommend you to try IaaS(SQL server VM) to get more control.

Answer (score 0):

It came forth that one of our developers has been reseting the password without telling anyone.

For now we believe this has been the cause of the problems. If it turns out yet again to be related to a policy I will re-ignite this question.

Thank you.